# How do I redirect different domain names requests to the same ip in django

Tags: python, django

I have one ip for two domain name, e.g. "www.example.com" and "example.info", and I want each of them to be handled as a different domain (e.g. www.example.com/photos and example.info/photos will be ahndled each by its corresponding function). Is there an elegant way to do this in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this by setting up different WSGI for each domain using a setting SITE_ID corresponding to the site id from the django.contrib.site app.